# Calling Asp.Net MVC 5 View from AngularJS Controller

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am trying to redirect to Home page after successful login. Currently, I am using ASP.NET MVC 5, AngularJS, EntityFramework 6, bootstrap and repository pattern. Below is the code for my LoginController:

```
public JsonResult UserLogin(STUDENTMANAGEMENTUSER data)
    {
        var user = repository.UserLogin(data);
        return new JsonResult { Data = user, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
```

code for AngularJS controller:

```
app.controller("mvcLoginCtrl", function ($scope, loginAJService) {
$scope.IsLoggedIn = false;
$scope.Message = '';
$scope.Submitted = false;
$scope.IsFormValid = false;

$scope.LoginData = {
    USERNAME: '',
    USERPASSWORD: ''
};

//Check is Form Valid or Not // Here f1 is our form Name
$scope.$watch('f1.$valid', function (newVal) {
    $scope.IsFormValid = newVal;
});

$scope.Login = function () {
    $scope.Submitted = true;
    if ($scope.IsFormValid) {
        loginAJService.GetUser($scope.LoginData).then(function (d) {
            if (d.data.USERNAME != null) {
                $scope.IsLoggedIn = true;
                $scope.Message = "Successfully login done. Welcome " + d.data.FULLNAME;  
            }
            else {
                alert('Invalid Credential!');
            }
        });
    }
};});
```

and code for my AngularJS service:

```
app.service("loginAJService", function ($http) {

this.GetUser = function (d) {
    var response = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: "Login/UserLogin",
        data: JSON.stringify(d),
        dataType: "json"
    });
    return response;
};});
```

I want to redirect to Student/Index.cshtml after successful login. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
return Json 
(
   new {
           Data = user,
           JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
           redirectUrl = @Url.Action("UserLogin", "LoginController")
       }
);
```

And then in angular in $http.post wait for a success callback:

```
success: function(data) {
    window.location.href = data.redirectUrl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not access a .cshtml view directly. You access it via an action method. So create an action method to return this view ( if not already exist)

```
public ActionResult StudentIndex()
{
  // you may pass a view model to the view as needed
  return View("~/Views/Student/Index.cshtml");
}
```

Now in your login success, simply redirect to this action method.

```
if (d.data.USERNAME != null) {
      $scope.IsLoggedIn = true;
      $scope.Message = "Successfully login done. Welcome " + d.data.FULLNAME; 
      window.location.href='/YourControllerName/StudentIndex'; 
}
```

Since you are doing a redirect ( a totally new Http GET request to the StudentIndex, there is no point in setting the scope property values.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it works. Another thing I want to know, I have to pass `$scope.Message = "Successfully login done. Welcome " + d.data.FULLNAME; ` this variable to /Student/Index.cshtml view. How can I do this?

Comment: You should follow PRG pattern. So query your user information in student/index and display whatever message you want to do